# Flutter web, icons render wrong icons

Tags: flutter, icons, flutter-web

After releasing a new version of my flutter web app to firebase hosting all my icons were displaying other icons.
For example instead of the arrow back icon, the attachment icon was displayed.

After refreshing all went back to normal. But it happens to all web browsers accessing the website for the first time after new version was released.

Answer (score 1):

Try to hard reload. In Chrome, open inspector (F12), right-click on the refresh button, and then select "Empty cache and Hard Reload".

Try `flutter clean`

Try `flutter pub cache repair`

Fiverr: https://www.fiverr.com/kamranbashir

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue before invalidating caches and rebuilding it fixes this.

do `flutter clean` first

check the posted issue [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/66343)